# Compact Framework - Keep modal window in front of windows bar after closing CaptureCameraDialog

Tags: compact-framework

I am working on a windows mobile application.  I have created a wizard that uses a modal window so that the windows bar is hidden.  One of the wizard stages has requires a picture to be taken.  After launching the CaptureCameraDialog, the windows bar appears and remains even after the CaptureCameraDialog is closed.  Is there any way to bring my dialog form back in front of the windows bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to find some code on the web that did what I was looking for.  Here it is:

```
public partial class myForm : Form
{
public myForm()
{
   InitializeComponent();
        this.GotFocus += delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
                             {
                                 //var intPtr = FindWindow("CaptureReturnForm", "");
                                 SetForegroundWindow(GetFocus());
                                 bool result = SHFullScreen(GetFocus(), SHFS_HIDESTARTICON |
                                 SHFS_HIDETASKBAR | SHFS_HIDESIPBUTTON); // 0x0020);

                             };


    }

    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "SetForegroundWindow")]
    private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetFocus();
    [DllImport("aygshell.dll")]
    internal static extern bool SHFullScreen(IntPtr hWnd, uint dwState);

    const uint SHFS_SHOWTASKBAR = 0x1;
    const uint SHFS_HIDETASKBAR = 0x2;
    const uint SHFS_SHOWSIPBUTTON = 0x4;
    const uint SHFS_HIDESIPBUTTON = 0x8;
    const uint SHFS_SHOWSTARTICON = 0x10;
    const uint SHFS_HIDESTARTICON = 0x20;
    const int HWND_TOPMOST = -1;
    const int HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2;

    const uint SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x40;
    const uint SM_CXSCREEN = 0x0;
    const uint SM_CYSCREEN = 0x1;
    private const int HHTASKBARHEIGHT = 26;
}
```